# Hibernate and Spring Use in Analytics Tools

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I want t integrate Hibernate and Spring Frame work in my product. But the thing that stopping me to use. Basically we have dynamic table and column name which change everyday. Currently getting data from table and displaying on UI is all decided at run time. which table to hit. same with the column names.

So how to implemented entity and other concept of hibernate and spring so the object will mapped to data?

for example this is the SQL

```
select t3521_250_1_1.f_1_1_31,sum(t3521_250_1_1.f_1_1_45) from t3521_250_1_1
where t3521_250_1_1.f_1_1_31 is not null 
  and t3521_250_1_1.f_1_1_45 is not null 
group by t3521_250_1_1.f_1_1_31 
order by sum(t3521_250_1_1.f_1_1_45) desc limit 5000000
```

in above Sql
Table Name = `t3521_250_1_1`

Column name = `f_1_1_31`,`f_1_1_45`

Now these table names and columns name are dynamic. Every day a new table is created with different name and this table has 64 columns but now I am hitting only two columns.

I hope you guyz understand what i want to say

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether this is a fix. But can you try creating a view with constant field names and point the POJO to this view.
When you create the dynamic table you can update this view as well.

Comment: its not about excel its about java entity class ..... how each execution will find which entity class to invoke

Comment: In traditional way, how does your system know the table/column names ?

Comment: meta and data both ae saved in dff dbs .... one contains the data other one meta like table names and columns info

Comment: Well instead of creating this meta info in a table , consider creating a view with those field name where the field names of the view would be consistent. Then you can use hibernate to call the view